signin with google provider with next js and firebase firestore adapter giving error [next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR]
On clicking a button I am trying to login but this gives me the following error
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
at callErrorFromStatus (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\google-gax\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:31:19)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\google-gax\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:357:73)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\google-gax\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:323:181)
at E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\google-gax\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\resolving-call.js:94:78
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
for call at
at ServiceClientImpl.makeServerStreamRequest (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\google-gax\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:340:32)
at ServiceClientImpl. (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\google-gax\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\make-client.js:105:19)
at E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\v1\firestore_client.js:227:29
at E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\streamingCalls\streamingApiCaller.js:38:28
at E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\normalCalls\timeout.js:44:16
at Object.request (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\streamingCalls\streaming.js:130:40)
at makeRequest (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\retry-request\index.js:141:28)
at retryRequest (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\retry-request\index.js:109:5)
at StreamProxy.setStream (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\streamingCalls\streaming.js:121:37)
at StreamingApiCaller.call (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\streamingCalls\streamingApiCaller.js:54:16)
at E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\createApiCall.js:84:30
Caused by: Error
at Query._get (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1738:23)
at Query.get (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1726:21)
at getOneDoc (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/firebase-adapter/index.js:276:52)
at getUserByAccount (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/firebase-adapter/index.js:120:35)
at _callee2$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/errors.js:365:29)
at tryCatch (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:45:16)
at Generator.eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:133:17)
at Generator.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:74:21)
at asyncGeneratorStep (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
at next (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:9)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:27:7)
at new Promise ()
at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:19:12)
at Object.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:83:39)
at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:208:28)
at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:69:28)
at async NextAuth.args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:105:16)
at async E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:53446
at async e.execute (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:44747)
at async e.handle (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:54700)
at async doRender (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1377:42)
at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1587:40)
at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1507:28)
at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1924:24)
at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1962:32)
at async DevServer.pipeImpl (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:920:25)
at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:272:17)
at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:816:17)
at async E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:339:20
at async Span.traceAsyncFn (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
at async DevServer.handleRequest (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:336:24)
at async invokeRender (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:174:21)
at async handleRequest (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:353:24)
at async requestHandlerImpl (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:377:13)
at async Server.requestListener (E:\Work_Folder\code-minors-lms\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:141:13) {
name: 'GetUserByAccountError',
code: 16
}
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@auth/firebase-adapter";
import { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { cert } from "firebase-admin/app"

export const authOptions = {
  secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
    providers: [GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    })],
    adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
      credential: cert({
        projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
        clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
        privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY!.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
      }),
    })
} as AuthOptions

Following is the code if I remove the adapter code the signIn works but when it is introduced it gives the above error. Please tell what to do. Anthing relevent will help me.
